# ASP.NET MVC -Working with Oracle and Dapper, using pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, dapper

I had to change sql server for oracle.

So I redid the query.

My query/Method on sql server with dapper was like this and worked perfectly    :

```
   public Pagination<User> ShowAllUsers(string name, int pageSize, int pageNumber)
        {
            var cn = DbContext.Database.Connection;

            var sql = @"SELECT * FROM USERS" +
                  "WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR Nome LIKE @Name+ '%') " +
                  "ORDER BY [Nome] " +
                  "OFFSET " + pageSize * (pageNumber - 1) + " ROWS " +
                  "FETCH NEXT " + pageSize + " ROWS ONLY " +
                  " " +
                  "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM USERS" +
                  "WHERE (@Nome IS NULL OR Name LIKE @Name + '%') ";

            var multi = cn.QueryMultiple(sql, new { Name = name});
            var users= multi.Read<User>();
            var total = multi.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

And next, is my query with Oracle/Method,

```
  public Pagination<Barco> ShowAllUsers(string name, int pageSize, int pageNumber)
        {
            var cn = DbContext.Database.Connection;

            var sql = @"SELECT * 
                        FROM (
                            SELECT ROWNUM rnum, b.* 
                                FROM (
                                SELECT * 
                                    FROM USERS
                                    WHERE (:Name IS NULL OR USERS.NAME LIKE :Name + '%')
                                ) b
                        ) WHERE RNUM between :pageSize * (:pageNumber - 1) + 1 and(:pageSize * :pageNumber) ";

            var multi = cn.QueryMultiple(sql, new { Name = name});
            var users = multi.Read<User>();
            var total = multi.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault();
         }
```

When changing the query to pl/sql format, I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid parameter binding Parameter Name: pageSize
```

How could I adjust this query to work with dapper?

Comment: And where did you pass `pageSize` (and `pageNumber`) to the query? `new { Name = name}` => `new { Name = name, pageSize, pageNumber}`

Comment: @Selvin Your observation is important, I forgot to observe the passage of the parameters. When modifying, I am getting the error from Dapper Reader 'Disposed Exception. `"The reader has been disposed; this can happen after all data has been consumed Object name: 'Dapper.SqlMapper + GridReader''. `" So I changed the variable "multi" to cn.Query, but now I have an error in the users and total variables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you're not passing your pageSize as a parameter?

```
var multi = cn.QueryMultiple(sql, new { Name = name, PageSize = pageSize});
```

Comment: ``pageNumber `` parameter is missing as well

Comment: @PiotrŁazarczyk good spot. His original code for sql server is also missing those parameters.

Comment: *His original code for sql server is also missing those parameters.* No, it's not - as he is not using those variables as parameter but he is adding it directly to the sql code

Comment: @Selvin you're right, he is using concatenation to build his query. This is slightly off topic but it would improve his query to use all those variables as parameters like he has with name.

Comment: not sure if it's possible with `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` in MSSQL

Comment: If that's the case, he should at least use string interpolation or string builder so he can build it more efficiently in code.

Comment: @nickgowdy I change the code, and now im using as parameters `var multi = cn.QueryMultiple(sql, new { Name = name, pageSize, pageNumber });` When modifying, I am getting the error from `Dapper Reader Disposed Exception: The reader has been disposed; this can happen after all data has been consumed Object name: 'Dapper.SqlMapper + GridReader'. ` So I changed the variable "multi" to cn.Query, but now I have an error in the users and total variables.

Comment: @Jhensen Have you tried using IDisposable to handle the connection in memory correctly? Take a look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510949/handle-oracle-database-connection-in-dapper